# Changing the labelling of the assumptions in the middle of the text

Tags: amsthm, newtheorem

I have the following document where I specify Assumptions 1,2 in the section "Main".

```
\documentclass[12 pt,a4paper, oneside, openany, notitlepage]{article}
\input epsf
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[inner=1.25in,outer=1.25in,bottom=1.25in,top=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
 \newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% name
  {\topsep}% Space above
  {\topsep}% Space below
  {\normalfont}% Body font
  {}% Indent amount
  { \color{red}}% Theorem head font
  {.}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}%Space after theorem head
  {}% theorem head spec
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{assumptionex}{Assumption}
\newenvironment{assumption}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\bullet$}\assumptionex}
  {\popQED\endassumptionex}


\begin{document}
\section{Main}
\begin{assumption}
Blah
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumption}
Blah2
\end{assumption}

\section{Extensions}

\end{document}
```

In the section "Extensions", I would like to introduce two other assumptions using the same style but I want to label them as Assumption 1' and Assumption 2'. How can I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new environment in a similar way to your assumption construction, but redefine the printing of the label by renewing the command `\the...` where `...` is the corresponding counter name:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12 pt,a4paper, oneside, openany, notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% name
{\topsep}% Space above
{\topsep}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{ \color{red}}% Theorem head font
{.}%Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}%Space after theorem head
{}% theorem head spec
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{assumptionex}{Assumption}
\newenvironment{assumption}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\bullet$}\assumptionex}
  {\popQED\endassumptionex}
\newtheorem{assumptionexp}{Assumption}
\newenvironment{assumptionp}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\bullet$}\assumptionexp}
  {\popQED\endassumptionexp}
\renewcommand{\theassumptionexp}{\arabic{assumptionexp}$'$}

\begin{document}
\section{Main}
\begin{assumption}
Blah
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumption}
Blah2
\end{assumption}

\section{Extensions}
\begin{assumptionp}
  Blahh
\end{assumptionp}

\begin{assumptionp}
  Blah22
\end{assumptionp}
\end{document}
```

Concretely I defined a new theorem `assumptionexp` and a new environment `assumptionp` and then redefined `\theassumptionexp` to put a prime on the number.